# How to measure MQTT (connect) message payload on AWS IOT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, amazon-cloudwatch, iot

I am using AWS IOT to send measures from an IOT device to AWS IOT. Now my network provider showed me how much data I am sending around and I want to see what messages are using all of the data. I was thus wondering how to measure the payload of the messages, especially the connect message.

Any idea, can I monitor this in Cloudwatch or with any other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details of the MQTT connect packet can be found in the MQTT spec (https://mqtt.org/mqtt-specification/).

You will most likely be using MQTT v3.11, so the CONNECT packet will be made up of a header

http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718028

- 2 Byte fixed header
- 10 byte Variable header (includes size of payload then flags for clean sesasion and if payload contains will, username, password)
- Variable payload (size in first 2 bytes of the variable header)

  - client id
  - will topic
  - will payload
  - username
  - password